# What does the Bajoran wormhole look like from behind?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, wormhole

The Bajoran wormhole has been a staple of *Star Trek: Deep Space Nine* since the very first episode. We see it opening up in all its grandeur in the opening credits as well as in many of the episodes. As far as I can remember, all of the instances of it opening (or closing) have been from a frontal perspective.

What does the Bajoran wormhole look like from *behind*? To be clear, I'm not asking about what the opposite *end* of the wormhole looks like (we see that it looks essentially the same as the Alpha Quadrant end), but what the entrance looks like when viewed from the rear. As an analogy, the *Stargate* universe gives us ample rear-view vantage points of open gates.

Was this ever explored in *Deep Space Nine* itself or in any licensed *Star Trek* medium?

- Does the wormhole look the same from any vantage point?
- Is the wormhole invisible when viewed from the rear?
- Are there normally hidden parts of the wormhole's opening that can only be seen from the rear?

Comment: For the record, we actually get very few views of the backside of a stargate wormhole

Comment: It's weird. I hadn't ever thought about it, but as a more-than-3d phenomenon, it would make sense (but is not required) if the wormhole had the same appearance from every 3d vantage point.  (Think of the appearance of a whirlpool from any point around it on the water surface.)  IIRC the view of the wormhole  (I wish I had some good screenshots) just from DS:9 varied significantly, which means that is _not_ the case; it must have a 3d anisotropy.

Comment: We've never seen the back of the wormhole (at least in the TV series). I can't think of any legitimate plot reason why they would approach it from the rear

Comment: @Valorum And that is probably a Good Thing.

Comment: @SpacePhoenix - The aliens that live inside it have enemies. Perhaps they might want to sneak up on them?

Comment: The Pah Wraiths went in the front way when one invaded the wormhole. @RobertColumbia which scene in the pilot episode of DS9 was the back of the wormhole seen?